# openCL kernel returns trash value despite no errors

Tags: c++, kernel, gpu, opencl

I've been following [these](https://github.com/Dakkers/OpenCL-examples/blob/master/example02/main.cpp) openCL examples. OpenCL isn't giving me any errors even when checking error codes with cl_int err, or from the kernel. But when I output the results of `landmap_flags[i]`, It shows I'm only getting garbage values back from the GPU. I could get the above example to work but when I included my data it started to break down. I'm also unsure if the `landmap_flags` array is too large for the kernel to handle? (`96 * 96 * 96` elements of `uchar`).

Kernel Code:

```
// CL noise lib
.
.
.
kernel void terrain_gen(global uchar* landmap_flags, global float3* pos, int LOD, int chunkSize) {
    const uint n = get_global_id(0);
    const uint x = n%(chunkSize+(2 * LOD));
    const uint y = (n/(chunkSize+(2 * LOD)))%(chunkSize+(2 * LOD));
    const uint z = n/((chunkSize+(2 * LOD))*(chunkSize+(2 * LOD)));
    enum BLOCK { STONE, DIRT, SNOW, GRASS, SAND, GRAVEL, GAETAN, BEDROCK, AIR };
    const float frequency = 500;
    const float noise_1 = (_slang_library_noise2(x+(chunkSize * pos[n].x),z+(chunkSize * pos[n].z))) / frequency;
    landmap_flags[n] = (noise_1*noise_1*40.0f+6.0f>(y+(chunkSize * pos[n].y))) ? DIRT : AIR;
}
```

The kernel is building fine and isn't returning any errors but I figured I could have an error with how I handle the data.

And my code for setting up buffers:

```
// set up devices, platform, etc.
.
.
.
    cl::Buffer buffer_landmap(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(cl_uchar) * 96 * 96 * 96);
    cl::Buffer buffer_pos(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_float3));
    cl::Buffer buffer_LOD(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_int));
    cl::Buffer buffer_chunkSize(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_int));

    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_landmap, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_uchar) * 96 * 96 * 96, landmap_flags);
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_pos, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float3), pos);
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_LOD, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_int), LOD);
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_chunkSize, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_int), chunkSize);

    cl::Kernel get_noise(program, "terrain_gen");
    get_noise.setArg(0, buffer_landmap);
    get_noise.setArg(1, buffer_pos);
    get_noise.setArg(2, buffer_LOD);
    get_noise.setArg(3, buffer_chunkSize);

    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(get_noise, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(1024));

    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_landmap, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_uchar) * 96 * 96 * 96, landmap_flags);

    queue.finish();
```

The way I intend for this code to work is to pass three buffers (`pos`, `LOD` and `chunkSize`) as scalar values, and only need to return the `landmap_flags` to the CPU. Could it be that I'm using incorrect arguments for `enqueueNDRangeKernel`? A possibility could be that my work group size is too large, or I have too many work groups.

EDIT: I edited my code, scalars no longer passed as buffers, the only thing being written and read is the landmap_flags, kernel has been edited for this as well to treat pos as a scalar value.

```
        kernel void terrain_gen(global uchar* landmap_flags, float3 pos, int LOD, int chunkSize) {
            const uint n = get_global_id(0);
            const uint x = n%(chunkSize+(2 * LOD));
            const uint y = (n/(chunkSize+(2 * LOD)))%(chunkSize+(2 * LOD));
            const uint z = n/((chunkSize+(2 * LOD))*(chunkSize+(2 * LOD)));
            enum BLOCK { STONE, DIRT, SNOW, GRASS, SAND, GRAVEL, GAETAN, BEDROCK, AIR };
            const float frequency = 500;
            const float noise_1 = (_slang_library_noise2(x+(chunkSize * pos.x),z+(chunkSize * pos.z))) / frequency;
            landmap_flags[n] = (noise_1*noise_1*40.0f+6.0f>(y+(chunkSize * pos.y))) ? DIRT : AIR;
        }
```

```
    cl::Buffer buffer_landmap(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(cl_uchar) * 96 * 96 * 96);
    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device);
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_landmap, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_uchar) * 96 * 96 * 96, landmap_flags);


    cl::Kernel get_noise(program, "terrain_gen");
    get_noise.setArg(0, buffer_landmap);
    get_noise.setArg(1, pos);
    get_noise.setArg(2, LOD);
    get_noise.setArg(3, chunkSize);

    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(get_noise, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(96 * 96 * 96));

    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_landmap, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_uchar) * 96 * 96 * 96, landmap_flags);

    queue.finish();
```

Comment: Why for `LOD` and `chunkSize` buffers are created on the host if they are scalar kernel parameters?

Comment: Also in the kernel `buffer_pos` is accessed as it was 1024 element array but on the host it's created as 1 element array buffer.

Answer (score 1):

[@doqtor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4899330/doqtor)'s observations in the comments are spot on, those are **very** serious issues.

Additionally, I've noticed the following:

1. Your `pos` buffer is created using `CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS` but then you call `enqueueWriteBuffer()` on it. (Though according to the text of your question, you actually want this to be a scalar, not a buffer? And then your kernel code treats it as a long vector as pointed out in the comments…)
2. You're using `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` to create buffers without passing the host pointer.
3. You seem to be submitting a work size of 1024 items, but your result buffer is for 96 * 96 * 96 = 884736 items and that's how much data you're reading from the buffer too. (This buffer size is fine, you should not be getting anywhere near VRAM size with that.)

Furthermore, you say that

> OpenCL isn't giving me any errors even when checking error codes with `cl_int` err, or from the kernel.

Given the misuse of flags when creating buffers, this seems… unlikely? Three of your four buffer creations should be failing with `CL_​INVALID_​HOST_​PTR` due to issue 2 above. I suggest you take another look at your error handling code. (you've not posted it, so I can't comment on specifics)

Comment: wow I suck at openCL, I modified my code (above) so there should only be a single buffer being read and written, but now I'm getting a different trash value returned from the kernel.

Comment: @HeartUnder8lade Getting there though! A few things to check: 1. are you sure your error checking is working? 2. What happens when you change your kernel to something like `landmap_flags[n] = n;`. Do you get the expected result read back? If no, your kernel is probably not actually being run. If yes, you can change other parts of your kernel (e.g. hardcode the arguments) to pinpoint where your fault is coming from.

Comment: Yeah I've revamped my error codes and now I'm really checking every single function call's error return code and constructor's pass by reference error argument, but still everything evaluates to 0 (no error), but, I did your suggestion and found that the kernel itself isn't running, so I'll find it eventually